# Converting Edit Text to long for Countdown timer

Tags: android, android-edittext, countdowntimer

I am trying to take the value from an edit text and use it to set the time for a countdown timer.  My code is below. Log cat is indicating an issue with 
line 63:"b = Long.parseLong(strInput);"

```
  if (!timerHasStarted) {

                String strInput = getText(R.id.ttext).toString();
                b = Long.parseLong(strInput);
                 startTime = ((b) * 1000);
                text.setText(text.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime / 1000));
                countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer( startTime, interval);

                countDownTimer.start();
```

Comment: Dear, what is getText(R.id.ttext) function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get value from EditText as:

```
EditText edttext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ttext);
String strInput = edttext.getText().toString();
b = Long.parseLong(strInput);
```